# Denied boarding - Who is responsible and how do I proceed

Tags: italy, uk-residents, egyptian-citizens, denied-boarding

My son in law is an Egyptian with a permanent residency permit for the UK. He was traveling from Manchester to Cairo via Milan. First leg of trip was with fly be second leg with air Italia. We contacted the Italian consul regarding an Italian visa and had an email from them saying he did not need a visa as long as he had a boarding card for his onward flight and did not leave the international area of the airport. I also contacted Milan airport who said the same thing. On arrival at Manchester he was denied boarding even though he was in possession of all the documents he was told he needed by the Italian consul. Fly be are saying it's the airports fault and the airport are saying it's fly be's responsibility. Who should I take action against and how can I do so

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96071/discussion-on-question-by-lindiloo-denied-boarding-who-is-responsible-and-how).

Comment: Since Lindiloo does not, I think, have sufficient reputation to participate in the chat, I'm posting this comment here.  Do not let flybe put the responsibility for denied boarding on the airport. If the people checking travelers' documents are airport staff, or any other company's staff, they are performing that function *as flybe's agent,* so flybe is responsible for their mistakes.  There is a similar question at [Denied boarding although I have proper visa and documentation. To whom should I make a complaint?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/135751/19400)

Comment: Thank you phoog. There appears to be some people on here who are not very welcoming to new comers who maybe do not know the rules

Answer (score 3):

Who should I take action against and how?

In the first instance, if you’ve not done so already you should contact the FlyBe Customer Relations team. If that doesn’t resolve the matter satisfactorily, and you wish to pursue the matter further you can refer your complaint to AviationADR, Flybe’s Consumer Dispute Resolution provider.

Consumer Dispute Resolution, AviationADR, 12-14 Walker Avenue, Stratford Office Village, Wolverton Mill, Milton Keynes, MK12 5TW

Telephone: +44 (0) 203 540 8063
Email: aviation@cdrl.org.uk
Web: www.cdrl.org.uk

Complaints can be filed online, via AviationADR website, or by completing a paper form which you can obtain from them via the telephone or email.

https://www.flybe.com/charter/comments